# Hidden checkout field Woocommerce for current user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to collect and save Wordpress profile photo of the current user who submits checkout form in Woocommerce. I would achieve this with hidden checkout field. Here is what I have so far. Not sure how to get profile photo of the current user and output hidden photo :

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_hidden_field', 10, 1 );
    function my_custom_checkout_hidden_field( $checkout ) {

        // Get an instance of the current user object
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

       // Profile photo

       // Output hidden photo

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pass the current users email address into the get_avatar() function.

```
<?php 

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
    echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 32 );
}

?>
```

Here are some links for specifics:

[get_avatar();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)
[wp_get_current_user();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

To output the profile picture

```
<?php 

echo '<img src="'. get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $current_user->ID, 32 ) .'" />';

?>
```

Comment: if it useful means please upvote.. if it is correct answer means pls put as correct answer...Thank you..